# PHP shorthand rewrite

Tags: php

Probably really easy for a pro, but could someone re-write this from it's PHP shorthand form to non-shorthand?

```
($facebook) ? $fb_active_session = $facebook->fbc_is_session_active() : $fb_active_session = false;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ternary operator - (condition) ? true : false ;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if($facebook) {
  $fb_active_session = $facebook->fbc_is_session_active(); 
} else {
  $fb_active_session = false;
}
```

Comment: Here's proof that not everyone finds the ternary operator easy to read.

Comment: I thought 4 characters was the standard.

Answer (score 6):

It would have been better and more clearly written (still using the ternary op) as:

```
$fb_active_session = ($facebook) ? $facebook->fbc_is_session_active() : false;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$fb_active_session = false;
if($facebook)
{
    $fb_active_session = $facebook->fbc_is_session_active();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:

IS **$facebook** TRUE **?** THEN DO THIS **:** IF NOT, THIS **;**